# Solving a set of 4x4 equations - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, linear-algebra

I am a student and have not learned how to solve sets of equations of this manner. I am working on a program calculating distances and times of moving objects along a curved path, but after I generate the equations, I am unable to solve them. Here is how they appear:

number = at^4 + bt^3 + ct^2 +dt

(there are 4 of them with different values for t)

For an end result, I would need to create a program that would take the input of the 4 different values of t, and the 4 "number"s that correspond to them in order to solve for a, b, c, and d. If anyone could point me in the correct direction, or give me some help on where to start that would be wonderful. Thanks

P.S I would offer code from where I started, but the issue is that I have no idea how to start, so there is nothing to add.

Comment: This is probably a good place to start: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html

Comment: *"I have no idea how to start"* - then you are not yet ready to ask a question here on SO.

Comment: This is not a problem of differential equations, even those were your motivations. This is a problem of linear algebra--solving simultaneous linear equations. Do you know how to do this by hand? If not, learn that first before trying to get a computer to do it.

Comment: This is a homework question and off-topic for the site
https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Dear all, This is not homework. Someone I know with no coding experience has asked me to complete a larger project (the rest of which I know exactly how to do) in which one small step is solving these equations. If it were a project in its own right, I would not try to do it since have not learned how to solve them by hand yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have four equations and four unknowns your best bet is linear algebra, matricies, and solving simultaneous equations.  Python has wonderful libraries for doing this.

If you have four points `(t1, n1)`, `(t2, n2)`, `(t3, n3)` and `(t4, n4)` your equations become:

```
n1 = a*t1^4 + b*t1^3 + c*t1^2 + d*t1
n2 = a*t2^4 + b*t2^3 + c*t2^2 + d*t2
n3 = a*t3^4 + b*t3^3 + c*t3^2 + d*t3
n4 = a*t4^4 + b*t4^3 + c*t4^2 + d*t4
```

Solve for the coeffcients a, b, c, and d using [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) and back substitution.

If you have more than four points you can still solve for four coefficients.  It's called least squares fitting in that case.

Comment: Can't see why this was downvoted.  It's correct, provides direction for a student without spoon feeding.  I think's unjust.  Explain yourself, please.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter. My guess is that, given the three votes to close (as of now), someone thinks the question is off-topic and therefore answering off-topic questions serves to encourage them.

Comment: I'd like the person who downvoted to explain.  There are times when I think that people go off the deep end here.   There's nothing wrong with helping somebody, even if we think their question isn't worthy or weighty enough.  The folks who downvoted thinking this was homework for a lazy student were wrong, if the OP is honest.  I see the point, but "encouraging" people to come here for help is not bad.  This one is far better than the millionth user who fails to understand basic algebra or trigonometry in radians.

Comment: @duffymo People love to jump on the bandwagon around here. I suppose if one is feeling put-upon by one's boss / teacher / parents / etc, it feels good to find someone even lower on the food chain. This is really the worst thing about SO, and social media in general. FWIW & have a nice day, btw thanks for your many useful answers.

Comment: I think a related problem is that we forget that one of Jeff Atwood's most important goals is to create an archive of good searchable questions and answers. All the "close reasons" are just hints to help pare away pollution from this archive. not ironclad laws. Yet from "searchable archive" point-of-view we have a reasonable question with a good answer for future googlers looking for help.